# continously getting error :unparsed apt error and the r.java file not regenrating

Tags: android

`**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="[http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android]"  
        android:orientation="vertical"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:weightSum="1">  

<TextView      
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
        android:text="Excel app-by Kanika Sharma"    
        android:textSize="20dp"    
    />  
    <DigitalClock  
           android:layout_width="250dp"  
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
          android:layout_gravity="clip_vertical">  
     </DigitalClock>  

    <ImageView android:layout_width="260dp"   
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/!bokaro-plant-photo"                                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"   
        android:layout_height="87dp" android:layout_weight="1.03">  
</ImageView>  

    <Button  android:layout_width="250dp"   
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:text="choose your department"  
     android:layout_gravity="center"  
     android:textColor="#FFFFFF"  
      android:id="@+id/dept"  />  

    <Button  android:layout_width="250dp"   
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
         android:text="meeting"  
     android:layout_gravity="center"  
     android:textColor="#6CA6CD"  
     android:id="@+id/meet"  
    />    
    <Button  android:layout_width="250dp"   
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:text="leave"  
     android:layout_gravity="center"     
      android:id="@+id/leav"  
     android:textColor="#4A708B"  
    />  
    <Button  android:layout_width="250dp"   
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:text="profit"  
     android:layout_gravity="center"  
      android:id="@+id/pro"  
    />  
     <Button  android:layout_width="250dp"   
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:text="Shift report"  
     android:layout_gravity="center"  
      android:id="@+id/shftrep"  
    />   
    <Button  android:layout_width="250dp"   
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:text= "Delay"  
     android:layout_gravity= "center"  
     android:id="@+id/delay"  
    />   
    </LinearLayout>**`
```

dats all i have coded......i read somewhere the solution for unparsed apt error to del and regenerate the r.java file.ideleted it but the error remains and the r file is not generating..plz help..the following does not help
1.clean project
2.del r.java file.
3.deletiing the error and rebuilding after cleaning

Comment: check console there would be something written there. there may be problem in xml file. It will notify in console or problems.

Comment: The source of your ImageView.. Is the name "!bokara-plant-photo" allowed? I guess not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your drawable name `!bokaro-plant-photo` to `bokaro_plant_photo`. I think it is the error, which stop the build.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:weightSum="1">
```

instead of

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="[http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android]"  
        android:orientation="vertical"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:weightSum="1">
```

and res/drawable name `!bokaro-plant-photo` then change it to  `bokaro_plant_photo`

Comment: "bokaro-plant-photo" is not a valid drawable name as well. Something like "bokaro_plant_photo" is.

Comment: @MartijnVanMierloo : i agree with you